# Why border-radius:200px is not a circle shape in Safari 5/6?

Tags: css

I used border-radius:200px to make the image to be a circle shape, it works fine on IE10, chrome, Firefox, but it's not a compete circle on safari 5 and safari 6.

My CSS code is:

```
.team-member img {
  display: block;
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  border: 4px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}
```

When I remove the border:3px solid #ccc, it works fine on safari, but I need keep the border around the image, how to fix this issue? Thanks!!!

Demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/badjohnny/kyfha/

Comment: It works fine on Opera 12.15 too. I have no Safari, however, did you tried just "border-radius" without any prefixes?

Comment: Yes, but it's also working not very good on safari.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. It seems that the 4px border is being applied only horizontally and vertically, the rounded parts have no border, safari issue?

Comment: Better use `100%` instead of `200px` if you want a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My impression is that this is a bug in Safari relating to using `border-radius` directly on an image; it is actually making it a circle, it just isn't making the border go around the edge of the circle, instead it's being cut off by it. I found one work around which may not be ideal, but it may work for you. Basically apply the `border` and `border-radius` to the parent instead. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kyfha/4/

And the CSS:

```
.team-member {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.team-member img {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I checked on safari, it still works not good.

Comment: Really? Works for me: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/357738/safari_circle.png What version of Safari are you using? I'm using 6.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: Well, I can't really testing Safari 5 - sorry. Could you show a screenshot though? I'm curious what it looks like.

Comment: Very strange! Try this? http://jsfiddle.net/kyfha/25/ I added border-radius to the image as well, which should mean it can't overlap with the border. Then I added a black background to the container, to get rid of the subtle gap there. I don't know if it'll work for you though.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine! jsfiddle.net/kyfha/25, It seems that I can't add border to the image, so add the border to the out container of the image. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a Safari bug, and seems that the only way to do it is by styling the img itself with the border radius, removing the outer div's 4px border and "simulating" it with margins:

CSS:

```css
.team-member {
    width: 204px;
    height: 204px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.team-member img {
    display: block;
    width:94%;
    margin:3%;
    height:auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="team-member">
    <img src="http://1.s3.envato.com/files/59524429/logo-s.png" alt="Johnny">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyfha/23/)

Tested on Opera, Safari, Chrome and Firefox, it works for me.

(Not tested on IE10 but it should work on it too)

Answer (score -1):

Based on your screenshot: http://d.pr/i/Z3E3 - try making the image larger, it looks like it has yet to hit the full width and height of 200px.

**Edit:** My apology for not addressing the border issue.

I might suggest the following: http://jsfiddle.net/jgagne/HPjzt/7/

CSS:

```
    .team-member {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: 0;
      padding: 0 0 50%;
      border: 4px solid #999;
      -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .team-member img {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; right: 0;
      bottom: 0; left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

**Update:** CSS addresses Safari 5 (Tested in Safari 5.1.7 and above).

```
    .team-member {
      width: 50%;
      height: 0;
      padding: 0 0 50%;
      border: 4px solid #999;
      -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .team-member img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: No, based of his screenshot you can see that the border is being applied only horizontally and vertically, the rounded parts have no border

Comment: I have tried, but no changes. only if I remove the 4px border of image, it will work fine.